# Laravel subdomains 404 - DirectAdmin + Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I just installed Nginx on my Centos 6 server that has Direct Admin. I can reach my domain, but the subdomains are not working. I get the Nginx 404. Ive added

```
|*if DOMAIN="my-domain"|

server_name *.my-domain my-domain www.my-domain;
 location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
|*endif|
```

to my custom httpd config. Does anyone knows what im overseeing?